# Why do some rules seem to work randomly? How to debug which rules are currently satisfied?

Tags: security, odoo-8, odoo, user-permissions

I am having some issues with some [rules](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/security.html). Some rules that are working one day, but they stop working the next day.

I am taking into account that the rules does not affect to the Administrator user.

I am wondering if I could print a logger message in the `ir.rule` model to check which rule domains are currently satisfied. I was taking a look to the model methods but I am not sure where to write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got to write the computed domains in the logger when each view is loaded:

```python
def clear_cache(self, cr, uid):
    _logger.warning('-- CACHE CLEARED')
    self._compute_domain.clear_cache(self)

def domain_get(self, cr, uid, model_name, mode='read', context=None):
    dom = self._compute_domain(cr, uid, model_name, mode)
    if dom:
        # _where_calc is called as superuser. This means that rules can
        # involve objects on which the real uid has no acces rights.
        # This means also there is no implicit restriction (e.g. an object
        # references another object the user can't see).
        _logger.warning('>> MODEL NAME: {}'.format(model_name))
        _logger.warning('>> COMPUTED DOMAIN: {}'.format(dom))

        query = self.pool[model_name]._where_calc(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, dom, active_test=False)
        return query.where_clause, query.where_clause_params, query.tables
    return [], [], ['"' + self.pool[model_name]._table + '"']
```

I realised they are only computed when they are not in the cache. When I update the module the cache is cleared. But I still don´t know why sometimes rules are not working well.